# Encoding videos for MPEG-DASH

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, encoding, windows, h.264

I read [this article](http://blog.streamroot.io/encode-multi-bitrate-videos-mpeg-dash-mse-based-media-players/) on encoding for MPEG-DASH, which has helped me a little and then follow up [article](http://blog.streamroot.io/encode-multi-bitrate-videos-mpeg-dash-mse-based-media-players-22/).

My end goal is to create a batch file that can read in a directory of MP4 files, and then output the configured video bitrates and MPD file needed for MPEG dash consumption by a client.

Previously I was testing with IIS Smooth Streaming, but it seems Microsoft is abandoning that and has been behind the progress of MPEG-DASH.  Their expression encoder 4 encodes videos very nice for Smooth Streaming, but they stopped selling the pro version that supports h.264, of which MPEG-DASH clients can play.  The free version does the VC-1 Advanced which is not supported by MPEG-DASH.

How to encode for MPEG-DASH?  I need it to be targeted to Windows as I have a public server that is plenty fast (Xeon) to encode and will be the delivery method to players as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would get as far away from EE as possible. Using the x264 tool, and mp4box, you can convert and segment out the files which are ready to be streamed to any dash compatible players. Especially since you mentioned using batch scripts, this is a great solution I think.

This is a good guide: https://web.archive.org/web/20141229070857/http://www.dash-player.com/blog/2014/11/mpeg-dash-content-generation-using-mp4box-and-x264/

Comment: Got it.  I had multiplexed representations in the MPD that was causing the player to trip up.  I was able to get around it by removing the ContentComponent in the MPD file, it played fine for me in Firefox, Chrome and Edge on W10.  Looks like to get valid MPD I need to demux and then run Mp4Box on those files for each adaptation set.  Thanks for your help, your link helped.  Marking as answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "EE"?

Comment: After some deep googling, reading white papers, I'm still not finding a conclusive answer to what EE is suppose to mean in reference to video encoding. I've come up with a few possibles: Event Encoding or EE Limited (a BT Group company providing mobile and internet services)

Comment: EE = Expression Encoder from Microsoft.